# How to implement Loader in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I want simple a "page loading" animation while my Photo is Uploaded.

So for that i have tried "blockUI" javaScript,
But somehow it not working for my form,

Here i have used a div as a dialog for uploading the image as below,

[image]

to submit or upload image i have used ajax call as,

```
function done()
 {
     var urls = "uploadImage";

    var str = $("#upform").serialize();
     $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            data:str,
            url:urls,
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() 
            { 

            },
            complete: function() 
            {
                $.unblockUI({});
                HideDialogInsert();
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            success: function(data){

                clear();
              }
          });
 }
```

And before that to do as i wanted (a "page loading" animation)
i have used as,

```
$("#btnUpload").click(function (e)
            {

                HideDialogInsert();

                $.blockUI({ 
                        message: $('#displayBox'), 
                        css: { 
                            top:  ($(window).height() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
                            left: ($(window).width() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
                            width: '400px' 
                        } 
                        }); 
                done();

             });
```

But it is not working,
it doesn't hides upload dialog.
but loader animation works in background of dialog.

So please help me to find a solution over it.

For BlockUI reference here is a link,

[jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos)

Comment: Why dont u supply jsFiddle ? Else All coders will hav to 1) Download This plugin 2)Create HTML 3) Add this plugin JS into HTML 4)Run file and then 5)See what is issue.So give jsFiddle with links to JS Library.

Comment: Here plugin is not my problem , it works properly!!!...My problem is that dialog is not hiding.....

Comment: Dude , i know But how can i see ur problem ? I told :  All coders will hav to 1) Download This plugin 2)Create HTML 3) Add this plugin JS into HTML 4)Run file and then 5)See what is issue.   Eventually u wont get answer.Who will do all above steps for u??? u can give js fiddle for us to see where is problem

Comment: Here it is...try it please.....[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mahiamali/6fqq9/)....

Answer (score 0):

If u want to hide upload dialog , use  **setTimeout() function before done()** function so that

block will hide and then further code will run.

Try this

```
$("#btnUpload").click(function (e)
            {

                HideDialogInsert();

                $.blockUI({ 
                        message: $('#displayBox'), 
                        css: { 
                            top:  ($(window).height() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
                            left: ($(window).width() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
                            width: '400px' 
                        } 
                    setTimeout($.blockUI, 2000);      }); 

                done();

             });
```

Comment: No dude...Its not working ...because it will surely timeout the  blockUI...not Upload Dialog....

Comment: can u share your test link